# Login/Redirection after registration PHP mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, registration, session-variables

I am trying to create a user registration/login script using php so that after registration the user will be directed to a page where it displays its created username and email.

I had my username and email based on two inputs during registration - the first name and last name, i.e. the user inputs: first name: john, last name: smith, then his username would be: john.smith and john.smith@domain.com, respectively.

I did this using these code

```
GetSQLValueString($_POST['firstname'] . '.' . $_POST['lastname'], "text")

GetSQLValueString($_POST['firstname'] . '.' . $_POST['lastname']. '@tatcs.com', "text")
```

After registration I tried to do a login script so that the user will be logged into the database and directed to "success.php" where it displays his/her username and email, with the username as the session variable.

However, when I tested it out, the new user was successfully added to the database but the success.php page failed to display username and email, meaning that the login was unsuccessful.

I think my login session code is the problem, since I do not have a textfield for username I cannot simply use $_POST('username'), instead I did:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}

if (isset($_POST['firstname'] ,$_POST['lastname'])) {
  $loginUsername=$_POST['firstname'] . '.' . $_POST['lastname'];
  $password=$_POST['password'];
  $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "";
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "success.php";
  $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "error.php";
  $MM_redirecttoReferrer = false;
```

Where I concatenate the first and last name to form the username as the loginUsername session.

Is there another way around this without having to add another username textfield? (As I would rather have the registration form be plain contact information and just have the system automatically create usernames from first and last names of employees. )

UPDATE: I followed mellamokb's suggestion to put the login code within the if statement of the insert code, but that didn't work for me. I thought the isset code was probably wrong so I changed it to

```
  if (isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset( $_POST['lastname']))
```

but still to no avail.

Please see below for the updated full code:

```
<?php require_once('../Connections/connSQL.php'); ?>
<?php

// *** Validate request to login to this site.
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}


if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "register")) {
  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO member (m_firstname, m_lastname, m_username, m_password, m_email, m_phone, m_cellphone, m_address) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['firstname'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['lastname'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['firstname'] . '.' . $_POST['lastname'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['password'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['firstname'] . '.' . $_POST['lastname']. '@tatcs.com', "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['homephone'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['cellphone'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['address'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_connSQL, $connSQL);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $connSQL) or die(mysql_error());

  if (isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset( $_POST['lastname'])) {
  $loginUsername=$_POST['firstname'] . '.' . $_POST['lastname'];
  $password=$_POST['password'];
  $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "";
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "success.php";
  $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "error.php";
  $MM_redirecttoReferrer = false;
  mysql_select_db($database_connSQL, $connSQL);

  $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT m_username, m_password FROM member WHERE m_username=%s AND m_password=%s",
    GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 

  $LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $connSQL) or die(mysql_error());
  $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
  if ($loginFoundUser) {
     $loginStrGroup = "";

    if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}
    //declare two session variables and assign them
    $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
    $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

    if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
      $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
    }
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  }
  else {
    header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
  }
}



  $insertGoTo = "success.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}



?>
```

I don't know why I was downvoted, I am a beginner trying to learn and I really hope someone could point me to the right direction.

Sorry for the long post and thanks in advance! I really appreciate your help!

-Allen

Comment: Your login code should go in the same `if` condition as the code that adds the record to the database, otherwise it never runs due to the `header(location:..` which redirects to another page.

Comment: Are you performing all these checks in one procedural script with conditionals?  Might I suggest you separate the logic if so?  It's trite to mention around here, but there are so many awesome PHP frameworks that can help give some method to this madness: Google for Kohana, CakePHP, Symphony or CodeIgniter.  It's my opinion, at least, that its best to learn one of these upfront and save the headache.

Comment: @mellamokb  Hi, so I followed your suggestion I moved `session_start()` on to the top and moved `if (isset($_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname'])) { $loginUsername=$_POST['firstname'] . '.' . $_POST['lastname']; $password=$_POST['password'];` to right after the insertSQL but it is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. It was actually having to do with my redirect page after INSERT. Thanks for all your help!